# GSON polymorphic deserialization cannot deserialize `type` property using RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, json-deserialization, runtimetypeadapterfactory

I am trying to use gson type adapter to deserialize my JSON. I am able to get the object back deserialized but the type property always returns null.

JSON:

```
{
"type": "rectangle",
"x": "3",
"y": "3",
"description": "this is my battle ground",
"children": [
{
  "type": "square",
  "x": "3",
  "y": "4",
  "description": "this is my arena",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "x": "0",
      "y": "0",
      "radius": "3",
      "description": "this is my inner circle"
    },
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "x": "0",
      "y": "0",
      "radius": "4",
      "description": "this is my inner circle"
    },
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "x": "0",
      "y": "0",
      "radius": "5",
      "description": "this is my inner circle"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Models:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract val type: String
    abstract val x: String
    abstract val y: String
    abstract val description: String
}

abstract class ShapeChildren : Shape() {
    abstract val children: List<Shape>
}


enum class ShapeType(val type: String) {
    SQUARE("square"),
    RECTANGLE("rectangle"),
    CIRCLE("circle")
}

data class Square(override val type: String, override val x: String, override val y: String, override val description: String, override val children: List<Shape>) : ShapeChildren()
data class Rectangle(override val type: String, override val x: String, override val y: String, override val description: String, override val children: List<Shape>) : ShapeChildren()
data class Circle(override val type: String, override val x: String, override val y: String, override val description: String, val radius: String) : Shape()
```

CONFIG GSON:

```
 val jsonResponse = loadFile("mock-response/shape.json")
        val adapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Shape::class.java)
            .registerSubtype(ShapeChildren::class.java)
            .registerSubtype(Square::class.java, "square")
            .registerSubtype(Circle::class.java, "circle")
            .registerSubtype(Rectangle::class.java, "rectangle")
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(adapterFactory)
            .create()
        val shape = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, Shape::class.java)
        print(shape)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Rectangle(type=null, x=3, y=3, description=this is my battle ground, children=[Square(type=null, x=3, y=4, description=this is my arena, children=[Circle(type=null, x=0, y=0, description=this is my inner circle, radius=3), Circle(type=null, x=0, y=0, description=this is my inner circle, radius=4), Circle(type=null, x=0, y=0, description=this is my inner circle, radius=5)])])
```

The `type` property is always null for child classes. I even tried to set it by giving it a default value in the constructor. Why does the type  property not get populated correctly? what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Shape::class.java, "type", true)` instead of `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Shape::class.java)`. The last parameter is `maintainType`. You had it set to `false`, in which case the type property is removed from the json prior to deserialization.